# F#: is there a way to mark a ref cell contents as volatile?

Tags: f#

I've come across a situation where a ref cell containing a boolean allows me to quite conveniently solve a problem of telling a spin-waiting loop to stop spin-waiting. I need to mark this flag as volatile (i.e. `[<VolatileField>]`) but such a field needs to be `mutable` according to the compiler, which is exactly what I don't want the reference to be -- I want its contents to be mutable, not the reference cell field itself.

Is there a standard way of telling a ref cell to mark its contents as volatile or do I need to roll my own ref cell (i.e. copy-paste the standard ref cell definition with `[<VolatileField>]` stuck just above `mutable contents`)? Well, correcting that for the fact that you cannot mark record fields as volatile...

Comment: The `Interlocked` API inserts memory barriers for when reading/writing `ref`. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Volatile.` or `Interlocked.` methods just work fine with ref cells:

```
open System.Threading

let refCell = ref 0

Volatile.Write(refCell, 42)
let fortyTwo = Volatile.Read(refCell)
```

You do not even need `&` or `!` before ref cells variable names, they are already references. `Volatile` and `Interlocked` methods are easier to reason about than `[<VolatileField>]` as described [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword).

Comment: this doesn't work anymore, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78005912/volatile-readmyintegerref-started-failing-in-new-net-version