# Volatile.Read(myIntegerRef) started failing in new .NET version

Tags: f#

Some time ago I had to port this C# code to F#:

```
using System.Threading;

public sealed class QueuedLock
{
    private object innerLock;
    private volatile int ticketsCount = 0;
    private volatile int ticketToRide = 1;

    public QueuedLock()
    {
        innerLock = new Object();
    }

    public void Enter()
    {
        int myTicket = Interlocked.Increment(ref ticketsCount);
        Monitor.Enter(innerLock);
        while (true)
        {

            if (myTicket == ticketToRide)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Monitor.Wait(innerLock);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref ticketToRide);
        Monitor.PulseAll(innerLock);
        Monitor.Exit(innerLock);
    }
}
```

So I decided to go for this implementation:

```
    type internal QueuedLock() =
        let innerLock = Object()
        let ticketsCount = ref 0
        let ticketToRide = ref 1
        member __.Enter () =
            let myTicket = Interlocked.Increment ticketsCount
            Monitor.Enter innerLock
            while myTicket <> Volatile.Read ticketToRide do
                Monitor.Wait innerLock |> ignore
        member __.Exit () =
            Interlocked.Increment ticketToRide |> ignore
            Monitor.PulseAll innerLock
            Monitor.Exit innerLock
```

The above has been working fine for years.

Until today... when my CI job started complaining... at **build** time! o_O

Turns out the invokation `Volatile.Read ticketToRide` doesn't work anymore, as it seems there's no such overload anymore:

```
Process.fs(22,31): error FS0041: No overloads match for method 'Read'.

Known type of argument: int ref

Available overloads:
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<bool>) : bool // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<byte>) : byte // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<float32>) : float32 // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<float>) : float // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<int16>) : int16 // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<int64>) : int64 // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<int>) : int // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<nativeint>) : nativeint // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<sbyte>) : sbyte // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<uint16>) : uint16 // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<uint32>) : uint32 // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<uint64>) : uint64 // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read(location: inref<unativeint>) : unativeint // Argument 'location' doesn't match
 - Volatile.Read<'T when 'T: not struct>(location: inref<'T>) : 'T // Argument 'location' doesn't match
```

So then I decided to change it to read the value simply via `ticketToRide.Value`, and it shuts up the compiler.

But is it correct? Is this property thread-safe? MSDN docs don't mention the word "thread" in [the docs about reference cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/reference-cells).